# After voting to close a question and retracting vote, cannot vote to close again: status-by-design, or bug?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

In regard to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57863/are-there-petitions-or-other-initiatives-to-support-the-master-and-associate-mas), I voted to close using a custom close reason. When I had finished typing and submitted, another user had done the same, but I liked his formulation of the, in intent, same custom reason better. I retracted my vote, intending to vote to close again by joining the reason given by the other user.

While my vote is not recorded (the question stands, as I type this, at 1 close vote), I cannot vote again, and am given the system-response "You already voted to close this question." If this is status-by-design, it's a bit misleading (the backwardness of my actions notwithstanding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be by design. It's the subject of [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction) on Meta SE, which is marked [status-completed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) now, but only because you can now cast a new close vote [after 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction#comment867915_200391).